# Fill a column from a concatenate range

Tags: vba, excel

What I have this far is below.

```
Range("F4").Value = Range("D4").Value & " x " & Range("E4")
```

This is creating a concatenate in Column **F** for me. This is working fine for the individual cell but I would like this to continue concatenating down until it hits an empty cell.

I have tried looping without success.

[below is an image of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JENRo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Concat= Rows(4)
concatstring =""
For i = 1 To Concat.Cells.Count
    If Concat.Cells(i).Text <> "" Then
       Concatstring = concatstring & " x " & Concat.Cells(i).Text
       Else
     Exit for
    End If
Next
Concat.cells(I).text = concatstring
```

This should do it. Let me know if you still have problem.

Comment: what should i put in as the target for the concatstring? Sorry for the ignorance

Comment: What do you mean by target? The above code concatenates for the fourth row and populates concatenates value in the first blank cell in the fourth row.

Comment: it is asking for a target object, but i cant see what i am doing wrong

Comment: Remove the set before concatstring. I have corrected in code above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 i=4
 Do while(Range("D" & i).Value<> "")
     Range("F" & i).Value = Range("D" & i).Value & " x " & Range("E" & i)

 Loop
```